# How to find current ref in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ref, use-ref

I'm trying to find out what the current ref is. The reasoning behind this is so I can trigger a popup whenever user tries to go into a section that is not the current section.

```
const section1= useRef(null);
const section2= useRef(null);
const section3= useRef(null);
```

I have sections:

```
const sections = [
    section1,
    section2, 
    section3
];
```

inside my nav I have links like this

```
<li><a href="#section1">Section1</a></li>
<li><a href="#section2">Section2</a></li>
<li><a href="#section3">Section3</a></li>
```

and finally i have the popup:

```
const TestPopup = () => {
    return <Modal
        ariaHideApp={false}
        style={customStyles}
        isOpen={openPopup}
    >
        Test
           <div>
            <PopupButton className="standard-button" onClick={() => {
                setOpenPopup(false)
            }}>Cancel</PopupButton>
            <PopupButton onClick={() => {
            }}>OK</PopupButton>
           </div>
    </Modal>
}
```

then inside the return of jsx I call each section like this:

I want to `setOpenPopup` to true whenever `section pressed IS NOT current.section`

so I was thinking of creating a setRef state where I can save the current section, and then have that called inside each `<a>` of the nav link.

something like this: `<li><a onClick={IF REF PRESSED IS NOT THE CURRENT REF SHOW POPUP} href="#section1">Section</a></li>`

Comment: Why don't you have a state that controls which section the user pressed last?

Comment: @Chris I do mention above that is the plan. I just didn't know how to save the ref properly, as when i try to console.log it does not return the proper value

Comment: It doesn't look to me that you need the refs at all. I would just do something like `setOpenPopup(2)` for whenever section number two is to be opened. If the value is 0 or null or something, then that's when no popup is open. You can then check whether or not to open the popup if the state value has the same number as the section number (in which case you don't open it). ALTERNATIVELY, use three state variables, one for each popup.